# Is there a way to initialize a `const` `struct` using `const` variables?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I would like to create a `struct` in C99 that encapsulates a null-terminated string buffer together with the actual string length:

```
typedef unsigned int uint_t;
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;

typedef struct {
    uchar_t * buffer;
    uint_t length; // excluding null-terminating character
} string_t;
```

However, I am encountering several difficulties revolving the `const`-ness of the `struct`'s members. Specifically, when I want to consume a function that accepts such a `const struct string_t`, and feed it with an initializer with const members, the compiler yells at me.

```
void show_string_internal(const string_t str) {
    printf("%s", str.buffer);
}
void show_string(const uchar_t * buffer, uint_t length) {
    const string_t str = // <== tricky assignment here
        (const string_t){ buffer, length }; 
    show_string_internal(str);
}
int main() {
    uchar_t message[] = "Hello, world.";
    show_string(message, sizeof(message) - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a warning over the highlighted line both in GCC...:

> warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type

... and in Visual Studio 2015:

> warning C4090: 'initializing': different 'const' qualifiers

Apparently, I am doing something wrong here. The only way I found to get around this is by declaring:

```
typedef struct {
    const uchar_t * buffer;
    const uint_t length;
} const_string_t;
```

But now I have two types instead of one, so I'll need to create handy ways to convert between the two, and I'm creating declarative sugar instead of using language features, so the code is less readable.

So my question is, as the title reads: is there a way to initialize a `const` `struct` using `const` variables for the members? Is there an alternative manner to reach the results I wish to achieve? If not, why not (please include references to official documentation)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tag lines at witch errors occur

Comment: Why aren't you making hard copies of the strings? Without that, `string_t` seems quite useless.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at all. You don't even need `const` in your variable definition there.

Comment: @Lundin In this scenario, I'm not making copies. In another, I am. The question remains the same.

Comment: I.e. you're using `const` in way too many places in a way that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin it wouldn't be useless, it would just be a non-owning access to data like c++'s string_view

Comment: Also, what's this with `uchar_t *` vs `char *` - they're not equal types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constness about pointer types should be read "from right to left" (and `"const T * buffer"` means "pointer to const content" actually, not "const pointer to content" nor "const pointer to const content).

So, you was about to use mutable pointer to const char buffer and use it for const version of structure (asking your const struct having mutable field - this is a reason for the warning shown). In case you plan to get rid of the warning you have to move "const" thing like that:

```
void show_string(char * const buffer, const int length) { // <== move const to the right of "*"
    const string_t str = // <== tricky assignment here
        (const string_t) {
        buffer, length
    };
    show_string_internal(str);
}
```

In case you plan to have const buffer itself as well, you have to redefine your string_t structure (or introduce as separate type):

```
typedef struct {
    const uchar_t * buffer; // <== add "const" here
    uint_t length; // excluding null-terminating character
} string_t;
...
void show_string(const char * const buffer, const int length) { // two "const" clauses there
    const string_t str = // <== tricky assignment here
        (const string_t) {
        buffer, length
    };
    show_string_internal(str);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your second version of `show_string` should be fine even without the extra `const`ness of the parameters. (Well, "should be fine" when disregarding the `char` versus `uchar_t` incompatibilities at least!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not at the struct level.
The problem is in the initialization of `.buffer` (`unsigned char*`) with
`char const*`. If you make `.buffer`  `char const*`, it'll work without casts, although you will still get warnings with `-Wall` due to different signedness.

Comment: I already gave that solution in my `const_string_t` definition. It's not satisfactory. Re the signedness problem in my example, I fixed the type discrepancy.

Comment: You can simply use casts to solve that. You can always access a signed integer through a pointer to its unsigned variant and vice versa (and you can always access any object through char pointers of any type). The casts in this context would be legal and without any aliasing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct has a member declared as `uchar_t *buffer` and you tried to initialize it with a parameter declared as `const char *buffer`. So the compiler complains because such would *remove* the presupposed constness of the memory pointed by `buffer` (such a violation is a logical error). Depending on what you need/want you may:

1. pass parameter as non-const,
2. pass as const, but then declare member as const in the structure,
3. use a copy semantic and allocate some memory to the member and copy values pointed by the parameter to memory pointed by member.

Also be carefull that `uchar_t` and `char` may not be the same type...

Comment: My question would be then -- would there be no way to enforce the `const` qualifier so that it would apply to the `struct` instance and all its recursive members? I fixed the type issue in the example, btw, thanks.

Comment: @Yuval it *does*. However the problem is that it is not the member whose constness is the issue, but the type of the object pointed to.

Comment: @Yuval const on a struct effectively does make all its members const. However, the const will be applied at the top level. You need the `const` at the first indirection (at what's being pointed to, not at the pointer).

Comment: @PSkocik thanks. I think this clarifies the issue at hand. When I apply a `const` qualifier to a `struct`, it refers to the direct values of its members. I wish to find a way to use the same struct type in the parameter list, while indicating that all of the direct *and* indirect values should be const (i.e. any `type * membername` should become `const type * const membername`). If I am understanding you correctly, there is no way to do this?

Comment: @Yuval No. As far as automated adding/removing const on indirect type components, C will allow you to do `T const *x = (T *x);` (with just one level) and that's it. You need casts for everything else.

Comment: @PSkocik thanks. This seems like an oversight from the drafters of C99/C11 - one can implicitly cast `int *` to `const int *`, but one cannot even explicitly cast `struct { int * }` to `struct { const int * }`. The only solution it seems, is to create a duplicate type for every `struct` type for which such a cast is needed, and to create a mechanism to cast between the two (manually casting each member to add a `const` type qualifier). I added another answer based on your replies. I marked it as 'wiki' - so if you have anything to add there, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have written, the problem has to do with the way the `const` type qualifier affects the `struct` aggregate type. All of the `struct` member values become `const` themselves. For pointer members, it only means that you may not change the pointer variable so that it would point at anything else, but whatever the pointer points to remains mutable. This is similar to what would happen if you'd declare an `int * const` variable.

There seems to be no way in C99 to endow `const`-ness on the targets of indirect (pointer) types that are part of so-called aggregate types. So there is no way to attach a keyword to a `struct`-type variable to signify that its pointer members should be considered pointers to `const` types, such as `int const *`. This is only mentioned by example in both the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standards, at the end of section 6.7.3 (Type Qualifiers).

This answer is based on correspondence in reply to Jean-Baptiste Yunès' answer, between Yuval and PSkocik.

Answer (score 0):

it is just the wrong constantness:

typedef unsigned int uint_t;
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;

use the correct type for size. In C it is the `size_t`

```
typedef struct {
    const uchar_t * buffer;
    size_t length; // excluding null-terminating character
} string_t;

void show_string(const uchar_t * buffer, size_t length) {
    const string_t str = // <== tricky assignment here
        (string_t){ buffer, length }; 
}
```